# Check if an Item's Property's value matches any from a list

Tags: c#, string, list

Say I have an object:

```
class Foo 
{
public string Comment { get; set; }
public int someVal { get; set; }
}
```

And then I make a `list` of them.

I now want to be able to match the `Comment` property against a list of strings, and create a new list, with all the elements whose `Comment` contain any of the strings in the other list. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you have a master foo object?? Or string comment?

Comment: What do you mean a master foo object? I have a `List<Foo>`, a list `List<string>`, and I wanna test each item of the list against the other list, using `Comment`, then create a new list if there are matches.

Comment: you should implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
var searchStrings = new List<string>();
var foos = new List<Foo>();
```

This should do the job:

```
var filteredFoos = foos.Where(f => searchStrings.Any(s => f.Comment.IndexOf(s) >= 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try this:

```
List<Foo> resultingFoos = listOfStrings.Join(listOfFoos, str => str, foo => foo.Comment, (str, foo) => foo).ToList();
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the lists you are operating with, it will be faster.